# What is the Jelly Bean listview design pattern used by the People app called? How is it built?

Tags: android, listview, contacts, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Been unable to find anything by googling, probably because I don't know what to call this UI pattern. The JB people app shows contacts on the left, and details for the selected contact on the right. The details fragment on the right has a triangle pointing to the selected contact. What is this Android UI pattern called? How do I implement it.

[image]

Comment: Is this People app specific to Jelly Bean? I can't find it elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Master Detail Flow template, which you can get code for if you start a new project and choose to use the MasterDetailFlow template (if you have the latest ADT updates).

As far as the triangle / arrow part goes, I'm not quite sure how Google does it, but this is how I would tackle it:

In the list fragment when an item is selected, it would have an ImageView with the triangle / arrow as its resource that matches the background of the detail fragment, align it to the right of the list row and make sure there is not padding / margin between it and the view's edge. You could either use a ViewStub (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) or just set the default visibility in the XML of the ImageView to invisible.

Then, in the callback for a list item being clicked, simply inflate or make visible the triangle image in the list row.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need anything explained in more detail.

Disclaimer: I'm sure this method I've described is not the best / the way Google does it, but this is how I would start trying to implement this feature.